# TimerTask is called repeatetly after time-jump forward

Tags: android, timertask

I have added one `TimerTask` in my android code:

```
private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do some task...
    }
}
```

and calling it as follows:

```
myTimer = new Timer();
//set the rate as 1 min
myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 0,
                    60*1000);
```

Now if I turn off the automatic time update(from network) and set the date as tomorrow's date then timer task starts running in every 5 milliseconds.

For this I don't have any clue why its happening and I need to fix this. I have already used handler instead but I want TimerTask to behave properly.

Please help me in this regard...

Comment: why did you go with `TimerTask` ih you already had `Handler` based stuff working?

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `scheduleAtFixedRate` and not `schedule` it tries to catch up with "missed" executions for the last day.

From the [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html):

> With fixed-rate execution, the start time of each successive run of a task is scheduled without regard for when the previous run took place. This may result in a series of bunched-up runs (one launched immediately after another) if delays prevent the timer from starting tasks on time.

Comment: So if I use schedule() instead of scheduleAtFixedRate (), it would solve the problem right?

Comment: I suspect, yes. Have a look at the JavaDoc if this suits your needs.